# How should the if statement look like?

Tags: python

Part of my code

```
list1 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt')[1]
list2 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt')[2]
list3 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt')[3]
list4 = getCol('/home/milenko/EDIs/site1/newst2.txt')[4]

mm1 = [line.strip() for line in open("m1.dat", 'r')]
print mm1
ii1 = [int(x) for x in mm1]
print ii1

s1= 1
dt1= 1
dt2= 2
dt3= 5
dt4= 6
er1=0.022

for item in ii1:
   if (item % 4 == 0)
   print s1,item,list1[item-1],dt1,er1
```

Out put should be like this

```
1     5     1         2.364       0.022
1     5     2        30.364       0.022
1     5     5         2.351       0.022
1     5     6        44.606       0.022
1     6     1         2.372       0.022
1     6     2        33.290       0.022
1     6     5         2.290       0.022
1     6     6        43.799       0.022
1     7     1         2.414       0.022
1     7     2        37.071       0.022
1     7     5         2.281       0.022
1     7     6        44.331       0.022
```

How should the if statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) will help you learn about *conditional statements* in Python.

For Example: (*As SO encourages to provide an example*)

```
>>> x = int(raw_input("Please enter an integer: "))
Please enter an integer: 42
>>> if x < 0:
...     x = 0
...     print 'Negative changed to zero'
... elif x == 0:
...     print 'Zero'
... elif x == 1:
...     print 'Single'
... else:
...     print 'More'
...
More
```

In your code, it should be:

```
for item in ii1:
   if (item % 4 == 0):
       print s1,item,list1[item-1],dt1,er1
```

Another Reference is [Learning Python the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex30.html).